# How to make a big image not scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-cycle

I have a jquery cycle slideshow that slides through 3 big photos and is behind the rest of the content. Works fine but the problem is that if I resize the window to less than the width (1400) or height (900) of the photos the scrollbar appears. How to make the scroll disappear or how to make the images "act" like background-images... Sorry about the confusion, hope you can understand me.

HTML:

```
<div class="slideshow"> 
    <img src="images/temp-bg.jpg" width="1400" height="900" /> 
    <img src="images/temp-bg2.jpg" width="1400" height="900" /> 
    <img src="images/temp-bg3.jpg" width="1400" height="900" /> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slideshow {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:-999;
}
```

Thank you,
Cris

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to set the height and width to 100% and set `overflow:hidden`

Comment: @user: Specifically, add `overflow: hidden` to your `.slideshow` rule. (No need to set `width` and `height` if you don't want to.)

Comment: I think you do need the width and height, otherwise how do you define "overflow".

Comment: @kingjiv: Nope, no need. The slideshow div will be as wide as its parent element allows it to be, and any content it has that can't fit in that area will overflow. Example: http://jsbin.com/uzuvi4 That's for the width. For the height, may have to set it to be `900` (not `100%`) to avoid the slideshow div's parent showing a scrollbar, if @user wants that.

Comment: Thank you! It works, but I seem to have encoutered a bug. If the browser is let's say 800x800 and the first image loads up; if I maximize the browser, the next image in the slideshow will not be 100% x 100%, but the previous browser size. Is there a function or a piece of code I can use to refresh the width & height of the images?

Comment: @T.J. that will cause scrollbars in IE (gotta love IE).  @user, what you describe shouldn't happen, I would guess there's something else going on.  If you have a working example you could post I may be able to help.

Comment: @kingjiv: In IE6, yes (good catch, I didn't know that). Not IE7 or higher (tested to find out). :-)

Comment: @T.J. Yeah, sadly work is just now getting off of IE6 so it's the behavior I'm used to.  Good to know that real browsers work in a more intuitive way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here's [the link](http://test.sopranowebdesign.com/temp/) with the bug I described. First load the site with the browser not maximized. Then after the first photo loads up, maximize the browser and you'll see the background images change dimensions.